How to resolve "this dApp could be malicious" warning in Phantom pepx?
i use anchor deploy program , next.js use solana-wallet-adapter sendTransaction,this dapp could be malicious phantom.  pepx.fun

Phantom and many wallets use Blowfish to flag unverified(by them) web3 sites as malicious
Please send an email requesting Blowfish to unflag your website.
review@blowfish.xyz
